# Filter added successfully but callback never get called - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, oauth-2.0, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to authenticate a rest-api request with access token. I'm using v3.1.9 of WP OAuth Server plugin available on [Github](https://github.com/justingreerbbi/wordpress-oauth-server) for OAuth 2 authentication. The requests are successfully authenticated with this plugin when testing on localhost. But, when trying to authenticate rest requests for a remote site it fails and `wp_get_current_user` returns `false`.

When I tried to dig dipper by debugging I found that the filter callback for authentication is never called. The callback for filter added [here](https://github.com/justingreerbbi/wordpress-oauth-server/blob/82c1710cd6d465c2d5b441525deb559c0b3ce14c/wp-oauth-main.php#L53) never get called and hence user is not authenticated for rest request. The filter is applied for a request by `_wp_get_current_user` function at line #2603 in [users.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/user.php#L2603) of WordPress core. I tried to add another filter for debugging but that's also not get called.

```
add_filter( 'determine_current_user', function() {
  error_log('****** determining ******');
}, 5 );
```

I can't find the underlying problem which is preventing this filter to being applied.

Comment: If you solved it, please share :)